# How to configure new google drive to resemble the old google backup and sync?

Tags: macos, google-drive-api, backup

I'm on OSX Big Sur, previously using Google Backup and Sync to sync files between my computer and google drive.

I have setup Backup and Sync to sync any files in the folder `/Users/doe/ODrive` which contains 16GB file size.

After migrating to the new google drive since backup and sync got deprecated, I see a different behaviour.

The new google drive by default works like rclone. It creates a virtual drive under `/Volumes/GoogleDrive` and at the same time makes a symbolic link to `/Users/doe/Google Drive` for quick access.

Here's my problem:

1. If I choose to access any files offline it starts downloading them on disk taking unnecessary disk space since I already have all files downloaded on disk but on a different location `/Users/doe/ODrive`. How do I tell google drive to use those files and not download anything?
2. Theres a preference settings in the new google drive allowing to choose your desired directory location for google drive. If I set up that preference from the current setting `/Volumes/GoogleDrive` ---> `/Users/doe/ODrive` will that mess my `ODrive` folder and its content? I'd rather die than loose its content.
   [image]
3. What's the difference between `Folders from my computer` and `Folders from Drive`. Isn't this two way communication like `backup and sync` was?
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I did a bit of research & testing on my end and here's what I have found:**

1. If I choose to access any files offline it starts downloading them on disk taking unnecessary disk space since I already have all files downloaded on disk but on a different location `/Users/doe/ODrive`. How do I tell google drive to use those files and not download anything?

### Findings:

> **It seems like this is not possible. If you want to tell Google Drive to use those files and not download anything, the only option that you can do is to select the [`Stream Files`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124#mirror_stream) option & then add the folder `/Users/doe/ODrive` on the `My MacBook Pro` preferences. This way, the files from your `ODrive` will be uploaded back to your drive instead. But, there's a catch as the uploaded files will be now be a duplicate because the Google Drive app will treat this as a new upload. And also, if you have Google Docs, Sheets, Slides or Forms on your `ODrive`, the app seems to not upload these files back & it will show you an error on the app's activity screen.**

> **Once the folder `/Users/doe/ODrive` on the `My MacBook Pro` preferences has been successfully added & synced, you will then see the `ODrive` folder on your drive.google.com > Computers (left side) > My MacBook Pro > ODrive. At the same time, the `ODrive` files are backed up and synced from your Drive to your computer and will also be available for offline use**

2. There's a preference settings in the new google drive allowing to choose your desired directory location for google drive. If I set up that preference from the current setting `/Volumes/GoogleDrive` ---> `/Users/doe/ODrive` will that mess my `ODrive` folder and its content? I'd rather die than loose its content.
   [image]

### Findings:

> **No. The Google Drive app will show you a message to reset the folder back to default because it has to be an empty folder before you attempt to change & save the default directory folder**

**See this result on my end:**

[image]

3. What's the difference between `Folders from my computer` and `Folders from Drive`. Isn't this two way communication like `backup and sync` was?
   [image]

### Findings:

> **On my observation, `Folders from my computer` is the section where you can see/access all of the synced folders that you've added from the Google Drive app, on the `My Macbook Pro` preferences. You can then view these folders and their synced files at drive.google.com > Computers (left side option) > My MacBook Pro**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers. If you don't mind me asking a quick one. Suppose we choose to download our stuff for offline use instead of stream. Then, we'll end with duplicate content on disk. Suppose we delete folder in `/Users/doe/ODrive` to free disk space. Since google drive has downloaded content to `/Volumes/GoogleDrive` what would happen if you exit and re-open google drive? Will your files be lost, since I expect to google drive to unmount from `/Volumes/GoogleDrive` on exit?

Comment: @KirkWalla you're welcome. On my experience, only the virtual drive `/Volumes/GoogleDrive` will disappear temporarily until you run the Google Drive app again on your computer but not the `My Drive` & its files. On the Drive app [documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124#mirror_stream), with `mirror files`, _all of your files will be accessible at any time, even when you don’t have an internet connection **or the Drive for desktop app running**. Files can be accessed through a folder on your computer_, which is the `My Drive` folder in my case. I hope this answers it.

Comment: If we answered your question, you may want to click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Comment: Thanks again, can we change the name of `My Drive` to whatever we want? Having a space in the folder name may cause clash with other software reading files from that location.

Comment: I checked on it but it looks like `My Drive` will be the default name on your computer when the app is running. You can still try to change the name of that folder but the Drive app will still set it to `My Drive` if it is running.

Comment: That's a bummer, it seems that they degraded the capabilities of gdrive, thanks anyway!